# Google maps javascript API recreate iframe

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm trying to "recreate" the iframe of the google maps api using the javascript api v3.
But i'm having some troubles finding 1 part.

example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#modes

at the top left you see a white box that says "directions / save as favorite" that's what i want, but i can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Why do i want this? i wanted to disable the zoom/scroll function when you scroll over the map to make it less annoying.

If anyone could help, that would be great!

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Don't have any option to disable it in google map embed/guide

try google map javascript and this: to eazy...

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      panControl: false,
      zoomControl: false,
      scaleControl: false,
 });
```

Comment: i already use the javascript and already have disabled the zoom.
i just want to add the white box in the example at the top left that gives users the possibility to get directions to the location on the map.

Comment: Follow this maby help : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places